# Times greater than an hours to this command ps aux | awk '{ print $10"\t"$12 }'

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-3.x

I would like to complement this command, taking the times greater than an hour

Times greater than an hours to this command `ps aux | awk '{ print $10"\t"$12 }'`

```
ps aux | awk '{ print $10"\t"$12 }'
```

Comment: Put a condition before the action in awk.

Comment: Really not sure that printing $12 is really what you want, but `ps aux | awk '!($10 ~ /^0:/) { print $10,$12} ' OFS='\t'` seems to be what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following command:

```
ps --no-header -ao etime,cmd | awk 'split($1,a,":")>2'
```

Explanation:

`ps --no-header -ao etime,cmd` will print only the execution time and the commmand line of processes. Nothing more. That makes parsing the command output a lot simpler. The output will look like this:

```
      35:55 /usr/bin/foo --bar
      35:06 /usr/bin/bash
   09:55:45 /usr/bin/long-running process
```

`awk 'split($1,a,":")` will split the first field - the time - by `:`. `split()` will return the number of parts the string has been split into. If it's more than `2` we'll print the line.

Answer (score -1):

This command does the job:

```
ps aux | awk '$10 >= 1 { print $10"\t"$12 }'
```